# Does the LinkedIn UGC API contains all shares of a LinkedIn organization?

Tags: linkedin-api

The UGC Post API of LinkedIn is characterized as

> an upcoming API that will eventually replace the Shares
>   API. UGC Post is currently best suited for creating and fetching video
>   posts. The Shares API does not support video. [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/ugc-post-api)

When comparing the results of fetching posts via Shares API and UGC Post API it seems that all posts retrieved by the Shares API are also included in the UGC Post API. But since this is not stated in the documention it's difficult to rely on. Is this the case?

Can fetching the Shares API be replaced by fetching the UGC Post API by now?

Furthermore, the UGC Post API seems to drop the activity-id/urn. Does that mean activities are deprecated? Should referencing of posts via activity-id/urn be abandoned in favor of post urns of type "urn:li:ugcPost"/"urn:li:share"?

See:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/ugc-post-api

Comment: UGCPosts will eventually replace the Shares API. As of today, the majority of Share types are available as UGCPosts, though full feature parity is not yet implemented.

Comment: Thanks. So I guess for the time being I better merge Share and UGC stream.